# Grouping and updating in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the most efficient way to group records by a certain criteria in SQL, assign a batch number to each group and then assign a sequential number (transaction number) to each record within the batch/group?

We have tried using temp tables where the transaction number column is an identity column but inserting to the temp table and then updating the records in the main table is not as efficient.

We could have multiple groups and each group could have up to 5000 records.  Assigning the batch number to each group is not problematic but assigning the auto increment number within each group is taking long.

- let's say there are 7000 customers in 5 different regions
- we have to group the customers by region (5 batches) and assign a batch number to each region
- within each region we have to assign a sequential transaction number
- the combination of the batch number and transaction number is used for identifying a record within a region (batch 5, transaction 1)
- The grouping criteria is not known at insertion time and therefore we cannot have an identity column in the main table

Comment: you want to update batch number and a seq number after inserting to  main table? you can use row_number for this. which dbms , sql server or oracle etc ? also post sample data, sample output and your attempted sql

Comment: title says Sql Server so added `Sql server` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can create these values using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY region ORDER BY region) AS UPD_Transaction
                    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY region) AS UPD_Batch
              FROM   yourtable)
 SELECT *
 FROM cte
```

And you can update a `cte` to apply them without temp-tables:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY region ORDER BY region) AS UPD_Transaction
                    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY region) AS UPD_Batch
              FROM   yourtable)
UPDATE cte
SET Transaction = UPD_Transaction
   ,Batch = UPD_Batch
```

Not sure what you'd want to `ORDER BY` for your Transaction number, so just left `region` in there.

Comment: Thank you so much...it works.  I have to store the batch number in a different table where we only store the batch numbers created. How would i get the value of the UPD_Batch since I can't access it after the update statement?  I tried setting a variable in Select but it's complaining.

Comment: @anita well, you could just run the top query and select out the fields you care about into a new table, then use that table for your updates.  Since it's tied to region, maybe just `batch` and `region`?

Comment: I tried storing the value of UPD_Batch in the SET statement and it worked.  @MaxBatch = Batch = UPD_Batch

Comment: One last question...how would I limit the number of records in a batch to be no more than 5000?

Comment: @Anita if you want to limit batches to 5000 records you can replace the `DENSE_RANK()` with: `(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY region)-1)/5000+1`, that's just 5000 per batch but no longer ties a specific region to a specific batch number, if you wanted to do both, you could concatenate a region code with the batch code, adding `PARTITION BY region` to the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong this is what you need. Use `Window Function` and `Stacked CTE` to do this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Dense_Rank()OVER(ORDER BY regions) batch_no
         FROM   yourtable),
     cte1
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY regions ORDER BY customers) seq_trans_no
         FROM   cte1)
SELECT batch_no,
       regions,
       seq_trans_no,
       customers
FROM   cte1
```

Comment: @Anita - There is a mistake batch_no should be using `Dense_Rank`